# Tornado : support multiple Applications when using multi-process?(NOTE:multiple Applications)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, tornado

Here is my code.

```
application1 = web.Application([
    (r"/", MainPageHandler),
])
http_server = httpserver.HTTPServer(application1)
http_server.listen(8080)

application2 = web.Application([
    (r"/appli2", MainPageHandler2),
])
http_server2 = httpserver.HTTPServer(application2)
http_server2.listen(8081)

ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I want to use multi-process like https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html.
What should I modify my codes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python tornado with multi-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371682/python-tornado-with-multi-process)

Comment: That is one application but my projects is consist of two applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support multiple `Applications` with multi-process mode, you must use the "advanced" mode with the `add_sockets` method:

```
sockets1 = tornado.netutil.bind_sockets(8080)
sockets2 = tornado.netutil.bind_sockets(8081)
tornado.process.fork_processes(0)
server1 = HTTPServer(app1)
server2 = HTTPServer(app2)
server1.add_sockets(sockets1)
server2.add_sockets(sockets2)
IOLoop.current().start()
```

Bind all the sockets (and do nothing else) before the call to `fork_processes`, then create the servers and add the sockets to them.

Comment: It doesn't work.The error is "OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use".The line is "sockets2 = tornado.netutil.bind_sockets(8080)"

Comment: Sorry, the second bind_sockets call should have used 8081.